# Error Code 220 - “Your credentials do not allow access to this resource” When liking/retweet/tagging

Tags: tweepy

I know it has to do with application authentication, but does someone know the correct way to use it instead of user authentication so that I can query more tweets per 15 minutes?

What I'm currently doing:

```
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The rate limits are in place because they don't want you to dedicate more than that much server time to you, for free. Don't attempt to circumvent these limits.

https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits

Comment: not very helpful, twitter has the following: User-authentication allows for 180 queries per access token every 15 minutes, application-only authentication allows for 450 queries every 15 minutes. this is official, but thanks for your input anyways

Comment: Ah, I thought you were trying to find a way to exceed their limits. I'm editing your post to better ask your question, accept if you think the change is appropriate.